# Joining two columns together into a datatable in aura

Tags: aura, datatable

i have a couple of questions.
So, first i have a datatable from a custom obj, where users can add or single email addresses or group of emails (like a mailinglist). There are two columns, one for emails and one for mailinglists. If Email is populated, mailinglist is blank and viceversa:

[image: if mail is populated, mailinglist is blank and viceversa:]

As you can see the table is very tight so would be good to show only one column containing both.
I tried this way:

```
cmp.set('v.columns', [
            { label: 'Destinatario', fieldName: 'Name',  type: "text" },
            { label: 'Email',        fieldName: 'Email__c', type: "text" },
            { label: 'Email or Mailinglist', fieldName: 'Email__c' ? 'Email__c' : 'Mailing_List__c', type: "text"},
            { label: 'Mailinglist', fieldName: 'Mailing_list__c', type: "text"},
            { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } }
        ]);
```

and i've got this

[image]

I am missing something in the syntax or what i'm trying to do is totally wrong?

Second question is: since mailing list fields might contain lots of email addresses, would be good to have kind of a hover to show the whole mailing list from that field which may get trimmed if it's too long but i've found out that datatable doesn't allow the hove.
Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ label: 'Email or Mailinglist', fieldName: 'Email__c' ? 'Email__c' : 'Mailing_List__c', type: "text"},
```

This won't work. `'Email__c'` will always evaluate to a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, meaning `Email__c` will always be selected. Instead, you need to combine the data in the object itself. This is typically done with the Array.map function:

```
let data = source.map((record)=> {
  const result = Object.assign({}, record);
  result.emailOrMailingList = record.Email__c || record.Mailing_list__c;
  return result;
});
```

Then you can set your combined field name appropriately:

```
{ label: 'Email or Mailinglist', fieldName: 'emailOrMailingList', type: "text"},
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it solved my problem!!!

Comment: And do you have any suggestion about the hover on datatable fields?

Comment: @Simon lightning-datatable should already be doing that, I would think? Other than that, you'd have to make the columns wider somehow, perhaps by increasing the width of the component or adding horizontal scrolling to the entire table by forcing it to be wider than the component's width.